# How do I streamline the development process in Visual Studio, with MVC3 multi-site commonalities?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am developing several MVC3 websites with Visual Studio, where the only difference between them are:

- two images (in ~/Content/Images)
- web.config in the root directory

I already have my models separated into a separate project, but the code for the the Views and Controllers are all duplicated for the sites.

How can I do a 1..* for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all sites are based on the same build, I moved the common files to the root and created a separate folder for each site.  Then with a simple batch file was able to accomplish what I needed:

```
for /f %%X in (websitelist.txt) do rd /Q /S ..\%%X
for /f %%X in (websitelist.txt) do echo D | xcopy /E ..\mybasewebsite.com ..\%%X
for /f %%X in (websitelist.txt) do copy %%X\*.* ..\%%X /Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Controllers into a separate project no problem.  Either with your models or in a separate project.

The views you trickier, I've never tried this but you could look at having them as a linked item from a shared source.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I coupled the views and controllers together.  I believe there has already been some discussion around linking directories within another.  Windows only creates a link short-cut.  I think in *nix land, there is a way to alias folders.  If this could be accomplished with Windows, that may do the trick... ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the only differences are branding (images, styles, etc), you could have a single project with a few settings.

For instance, if the logo is different for each web site, you could add a `LogoUrl` setting via the Settings tab in your project properties or in the `<appSettings>` section of your web.config.

Then in your view, reference that setting instead of the hard coded path:

```
<img src="@Settings.Default.LogoUrl" alt="Logo" />
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, however not feasible, if trying to build with a build script.

Comment: I do this with an msbuild script. You can add multiple solution configurations and web.config transformations to apply the different settings.